# Unity 3d Animator Apply root motion prevent overrides transform.position assignment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey all I have a situation where I have a networked client whom I move with position updates and set the network client position directly:
`transform.position = StateSelector.Iknstance.GetCharacter(_player.PlayerId).State.Position;`

I started using an Animator for players with the flag "Apply root motion" turned on. (some animations I use do require movement)

This overrides the transform position assignment I've mentioned above.

Do you have any suggestions on how can I assign the position without it being overwritten?

So far I've managed to use `CharacterController.Move()` with the deltaPosition however I think there should be a better way than doing this...

Thank you all for reading this.